# Как решить задачу с помощью динамического программирования?

Tags: алгоритм, динамическое-программирование

**Условие задачи:**
Заяц может только разгоняться. Если он прыгнул на n кочек вперёд, то следующий прыжок не может быть меньше n. Нужно определить кол-во способов добраться до i кочки, причём последний прыжок равен k.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот объяснение и решение задачи от лектора, но я его не понял -  https://youtu.be/P6-7bcuPs3k?t=4275

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пусть `c(i, k)` - число способов доскакать до позиции `i` при условии что последний скачок не более `k` кочек.

Как формулируется требуемый в задаче результат в терминах функции `c`? Последний скачок ровно `k` - предыдущая кочка `i - k`. Заяц не тормозит, его скорость на кочке `i - k` не должна превосходить `k` (иначе заяц не может сделать последний скачок).

Нам надо вычислить `c(i - k, k)`.

Какие есть свойства у функции `c`?

1. `c(i, *) = 0, i < 0` - ноль способов быть левее первой кочки (пока в этом нет смысла, позже он появится);
2. `c(1, *) = 1` - на первую кочку заяц может "прибыть" на первую кочку только одним способом;
3. `c(i, k) = sum(c(i - j, j) | j in [1, k])` - чтобы попасть на кочку `i`, надо попасть на одну из кочек в диапазоне `[i - k, i - 1]`. Скорость на кочке не должна быть слишком велика, чтобы не проскочить мимо `i`. (Первый пункт обретает смысл: суммирование можно делать и до первой кочки).

Если вам что-то неясно в этих пунктах, задайте вопрос.

Если вам всё понятно, то вы готовы написать функцию `c`. Добавьте к ней кеш, получится "динамическое программирование".

Comment: Откуда появилась переменная j, что такое | и in? И там написано "Чтобы попасть на кочку k", может на кочку i? Большое спасибо за ответ!

Comment: это сумма `c(i-1, 1) + c(i-2, 2) + ... + c(i-k, k)`. `j` - параметр суммирования. Ошибки после "чтобы" поправил. Спасибо.

Comment: "чтобы попасть на кочку `i`, надо попасть на одну из кочек в диапазоне `[i - k, i - 1]`" - Последний прыжок должен быть равен `k`, когда мы прыгаем на кочку `i`. То есть рассчитать `c(i, k)`. Тогда нам нужно рассчитать кол-во вариантов попасть на `i-k` за прыжок, который меньше или равен `k`. Но если мы будем на кочках от `i-k` до `i-1`, то мы не сможем сделать последний прыжок :) Сложная задачка

Comment: аа, кажется вы сразу свели задачу к нахождению числу способов допрыгнуть до i-той кочки, где последний прыжок меньше или равен `k`

Comment: Задачка не сложная если вы знаете методику: придумываете функцию, которая вычисляет ответ, придумываете какие у неё есть свойства. Получилось - хорошо. Не получилось - придумываете другую функцию. Если набить руку, такие задачи решаются в пять минут.

Comment: https://codepen.io/koxnkqsq/pen/JjOeQdq?editors=1111 Вроде работает